# VBA Copy Last 3 Cells of a Column

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way that I can copy the last 3 cells of an entire column? In this instance, column B? Thanks!

```
Sub LastThree()

    Worksheets("DATA").Activate

    With Sheets("DATA")
        ' Adds titles to forecast columns
        .Range("I1").Value = "Production Forecast"
        .Range("J1").Value = "Demand Forecast"
        .Range("K1").Value = "Inventory Forecast"
    End With

    With Sheets("DATA")
        Worksheets("DATA").Activate
        .Range("B:B" - 3).Copy
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean if the data is from B1:B20 then you want data from B18:B20?

Comment: Yes! But it must adapt if the column expands.

Comment: Check the answer that has been posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the block `With` you don't need to use  `.Activate`.

First you calculate the last row, and then you substract 3 when taking the first cell:

```
Option Explicit
Sub LastThree()

    With Sheets("DATA")
    ' Adds titles to forecast columns
        .Range("I1") = "Production Forecast"
        .Range("J1") = "Demand Forecast"
        .Range("K1") = "Inventory Forecast"
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(LastRow - 2, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2)).Copy
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastThree()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim arrHeaders As Variant

    arrHeaders = Split("Production Forecast,Demand Forecast,Inventory Forecast", ",")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Adds titles to forecast columns
        .Range("I1:K1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrHeaders)

        .Range("B" & LastRow - 2 & ":B" & LastRow).Copy

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @PaperCupStraw if the answer helps you please vote to help others with the same question.